# Issue while pushing ABNewPersonViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, abaddressbook, addressbookui

I am using AddressBookUI Framework for Adding contact, when I tried to pushing this view controller then cancel and done button not working properly, I don't want to present it

Here is my code

```
ABNewPersonViewController *abnpvc = [[ABNewPersonViewController alloc] init];
[abnpvc setNewPersonViewDelegate: self];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:abnpvc animated:YES];
```

I am also tried add as subview rather then pushing it but when I am adding as subview then it was not added

As per **comment** i have tried like

```
UINavigationController *navigation = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:abnpvc];
[self presentViewController:navigation animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Can anyone help me out why properly not working ?

Comment: The docs state that ' It is recommended that you present a new-person view controller modally.'.

Comment: @JanGreve i have also tried this, i have updated question not working buttons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement that too considering also the other answers and the deprecations to `ABNewPersonViewController` in iOS 9.

As per your remarks:

> cancel and done button not working properly

They are working if you have included the `ABNewPersonViewControllerDelegate` on interface like this:

```
@interface ViewController () <ABNewPersonViewControllerDelegate>
```

Pushing the viewController on navigation stack like this:

```
ABNewPersonViewController *controller = [[ABNewPersonViewController alloc] init];
controller.newPersonViewDelegate = self;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

And by conforming to the protocol by implementing this method:

```
- (void)newPersonViewController:(ABNewPersonViewController *)newPersonView didCompleteWithNewPerson:(nullable ABRecordRef)person {
    // Trick to go back to your view by popping it from the navigation stack when done or cancel button is pressed
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

The tricky line is to pop the newPersonController from the navigation stack when either **Done** or **Cancel** button are pressed.

Enjoy it

Comment: Thanks it works, but one more question i have filled all detail how can i get the detail that i have filled in form ?

Comment: You have the person (nullable ABRecordRef) variable which holds your data

Comment: when i tried to print that details it comes like  `<CPRecord: 0x7f9bb0faf8d0 ABPerson>` this how can i getting object ?

Comment: Please look [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AddressBook/Tasks/AccessingData.html) how to access it's data as this is an encoded object which will log the reference

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you just do it as [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AddressBookUI/Reference/ABNewPersonViewController_Class/index.html) say?

> It is recommended that you present a new-person view controller modally.

Use

```
ABNewPersonViewController *abnpvc = [[ABNewPersonViewController alloc] init];
[abnpvc setNewPersonViewDelegate: self];
[self presentViewController:abnpvc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

That should work fine.

**Edit**

On second thought, did you set your delegate correctly and do the implementations get called? I suspect they are not implemented or the delegate is not set correctly.

Comment: thanks for your answer i have updated my question i have already tried via presening view controllor not working buttons for me and also when i tried to run your code there is no any button cancel or done so we have to use navigationbar right ?

Answer (score 1):

Apple guideline(IMPORTANT) :: New-person view controllers must be used with a navigation controller in order to function properly. It is recommended that you present a new-person view controller modally.

Add Delegate

```
@interface ViewController () <ABNewPersonViewControllerDelegate>
```

Pushing the viewController

```
ABNewPersonViewController *abnpvc = [[ABNewPersonViewController alloc] init];
[abnpvc setNewPersonViewDelegate: self];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:abnpvc];
[self presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
```

And Now Add Delegate Method

```
#pragma mark ABNewPersonViewControllerDelegate methods

- (void)newPersonViewController:(ABNewPersonViewController *)newPersonViewController didCompleteWithNewPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

That will work fine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer , I tried your code but problem is buttons are not working cancel or done